# How to pass data through MVC for C++ (possibly using vectors or pointers)

Tags: c++, model-view-controller, vector

So I have a project in which I must parse a data file, and dynamically create instances of a class `Sensor` while passing in the parsed data to that class. I am storing these instances in a vector of object pointers, `sensors`. Once the data is passed into each instance of `Sensor`, inside the `Sensor` class I must generate a `reading` value using the `min` and `max` values passed in from the parser. Then all of the values, `min, max, type, reading, material, id` must be passed to a controller class called `SensorMount` . This class is responsible for routing the data to a `DisplayDevice`class that I have not yet implemented.

I am confused on how to implement my controller `SensorMount` class. I know I need to use my `get` functions in the `Sensor` class, but I just am not sure where to start with this. Would another vector of `Sensor` object instances work? That is my current idea but I'm not sure if that is possible. I know sending a "message object" (Stated by my prof) could work but I can't seem to find any implementation of one online. I really appreciate any help and patience, I'm new to this and feel really stuck.

Also, I see alot of people on stack overflow condemn the use of `using namespace` but my professor wants us to use it. And we are not to implement a design pattern for this program (I know observer would work) , we will do that in the next.

Simulation.cpp (Where data parser is called and vector is created and initial data is passed )

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "Simulation.hpp"
#include "EnviroSimDataParser.h"

Simulation::Simulation() {}
Simulation::~Simulation(){}

void Simulation::initializeSimulation() {

char fileName[64];
char m_sType[64];
char m_sMaterial[64];
int m_iID;
char m_sUnits[64];
double m_sMinVal;
double m_sMaxVal;
char type[64];
int IDs[8];
int IDCount;
cout << "Enter the name of the data file:" << endl;
cin >> fileName ;
//cout << fileName << "\n" ;

parser = new EnviroSimDataParser(fileName);
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++){
parser ->getSensorData(m_sType, m_sMaterial, &m_iID, m_sUnits, &m_sMinVal, &m_sMaxVal);
sensors.push_back(new Sensor(m_sType, m_sMaterial, m_iID, m_sUnits, m_sMinVal, m_sMaxVal));
cout << "success " << m_iID << endl;
}
for (int x = 0; x <4; x++){
parser -> getDisplayData(type, IDs, &IDCount);
//if (strcmp(type, ""))
}
mount = new SensorMount();
display = new Display();

}

void Simulation::runSimulation(){
}
```

Sensor.cpp

```
#include "Sensor.hpp"

Sensor::Sensor(char *SensorType, char *SensorMaterial, int SensorID, char *SensorUnit, double MaxVal, double MinVal) {
strcpy(type, SensorType);
strcpy(material, SensorMaterial);
ID = SensorID;
strcpy(unit, SensorUnit);
max = MaxVal;
min = MinVal;
}
Sensor::Sensor(){}
Sensor::~Sensor()
{
}

double Sensor::generateReading(){
reading = min + (rand() % (int)(max - min + 1));
cout << reading<< endl;
return reading;
}

char * Sensor::getType(){
return type;
}
char * Sensor::getMaterial(){
return material;
}
int Sensor::getID(){
return ID;
}
char * Sensor::getUnit(){
return unit;
}
double Sensor::getMin(){
return min;
}
double Sensor::getMax(){
return max;
}
double Sensor::getReading(){
return reading;
}

//void Sensor::sendSensorData(){
// SensorMount.routeData(Display)
//}
```

Sensor.h

```
#ifndef Sensor_hpp
#define Sensor_hpp

#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

class Sensor
{
public:
Sensor();
Sensor(char *SensorType, char *SensorMaterial, int SensorID, char *SensorUnit, double MaxVal, double MinVal);
~Sensor();
//virtual Sensor updateSensor();
char * getType();
char * getMaterial();
int getID();
char * getUnit();
double getMin();
double getMax();
double getReading();
private:
char type[32];
char material[32];
int ID;
int reading;
char unit[32];
double min;
double max;
double generateReading();
};
#endif /* Sensor_hpp */
```

SensorMount.h (controller)

```
#ifndef SensorMount_hpp
#define SensorMount_hpp

#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector.
#include "Sensor.hpp"
#include "Display.hpp"

using namespace std;

class SensorMount{
private:
Sensor *sensors;
Display *displayDevices;
vectorgetSensorData;
public:
SensorMount();
~SensorMount();


};

#endif /* SensorMount_hpp */
```

Comment: "I know sending a "message object" (Stated by my prof) could work" and "And we are not to implement a design pattern for this program (I know observer would work)" seem a little contradictory. And... MVC is also a design pattern (one of the most limiting and imo, vile in existence). I'd say before going any further, none of the pointers you've created (except maybe `char*` but even they could be `std::string`) actually need to be pointers, you should think about how to eliminate them as your code will be so much better for it.

Comment: And `using namespace std;` pretty much always sucks when used in header files, i'd ignore your prof on that one.

Comment: @George I know, but he wants us to use all those pointers :/ he loves pointers. But on the message object, how exactly could I implement a message? I just know our next project will implement the observer pattern, he said we didn't need to do that for this but we could use a message object to route data. I just dont know how

Comment: That's the thing, setting up messages usually means implementing the observer pattern. Anyway, it's a little bad, but assuming `DisplayDevice` is the same thing as `Display` in your code, you could get rid of `SensorMount` and hand `Display` the `this` pointer in `Simulation::initializeSimulation`, so might look something like `class Display{ _simulation; public: Display(Simulation* simulation) : _simulation(simulation) { } };` and initialising the `Display` just becomes `display = new Display(this);`

Comment: ah I thought of that but we have to have SensorMount, we have to have that controller class. It would be so much easier to hand the data otherwise.